# How to send a dynamically generate zipfile to the client

Tags: python, json, flask, python-zipfile

I am looking for a way to send a zipfile to the client that is generated from a requests response. In this example, I send a JSON string to a URL which returns a zip file of the converted JSON string.

```
@app.route('/sendZip', methods=['POST'])
def sendZip():
    content = '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-105.01621, 39.57422]}'
    data = {'json' : content}
    r = requests.post('http://ogre.adc4gis.com/convertJson', data = data)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        zipDoc = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
        return Response(zipDoc,
                mimetype='application/zip',
                headers={'Content-Disposition':'attachment;filename=zones.zip'})
```

But my zip file is empty and the error returned by flask is

```
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response 
headers were already sent
```

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337013/how-to-send-zip-files-in-the-python-flask-framework

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should return the file *directly*, not a `ZipFile()` object:

```
r = requests.post('http://ogre.adc4gis.com/convertJson', data = data)
if r.status_code == 200:
    return Response(r.content,
            mimetype='application/zip',
            headers={'Content-Disposition':'attachment;filename=zones.zip'})
```

The response you receive is indeed a zipfile, but there is no point in having Python parse it and give you unzipped contents, and Flask certainly doesn't know what to do with that object.