# How to send zip files in the python Flask framework?

Tags: python, http, flask, zip

I have a flask server that grabs binary data for several different files from a database and puts them into a python 'zipfile' object.  I want to send the generated zip file with my code using flask's "send_file" method.

I was originally able to send non-zip files successfully by using the BytesIO(bin) as the first argument to send_file, but for some reason I can't do the same thing with my generated zip file.  It gives the error:

'ZipFile' does not have the buffer interface.

How do I send this zip file object to the user with Flask?

This is my code:

```
@app.route("/getcaps",methods=['GET','POST'])
def downloadFiles():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mongo = MongoDAO('localhost',27017)
        identifier = request.form['CapsuleName']
        password = request.form['CapsulePassword']
        result = mongo.getCapsuleByIdentifier(identifier,password)
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile('capsule.zip','w')
        files = result['files']
        for individualFile in files:
            data = zipfile.ZipInfo(individualFile['fileName'])
            data.date_time = time.localtime(time.time())[:6]
            data.compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
            zf.writestr(data,individualFile['fileData'])
        return send_file(BytesIO(zf), attachment_filename='capsule.zip', as_attachment=True)
    return render_template('download.html')
```

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513542/flask-how-to-send-a-dynamically-generate-zipfile-to-the-client

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`BytesIO()` needs to be passed *bytes data*, but a `ZipFile()` object is not bytes-data; you actually created a file *on your harddisk*.

You can create a `ZipFile()` in memory by using `BytesIO()` *as the base*:

```
memory_file = BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(memory_file, 'w') as zf:
    files = result['files']
    for individualFile in files:
        data = zipfile.ZipInfo(individualFile['fileName'])
        data.date_time = time.localtime(time.time())[:6]
        data.compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
        zf.writestr(data, individualFile['fileData'])
memory_file.seek(0)
return send_file(memory_file, attachment_filename='capsule.zip', as_attachment=True)
```

The `with` statement ensures that the `ZipFile()` object is properly closed when you are done adding entries, causing it to write the required trailer to the in-memory file object. The `memory_file.seek(0)` call is needed to 'rewind' the read-write position of the file object back to the start.

Comment: How would I do this when I just have `files = ['filename1', 'filename2']` i.e. files on the server site which I would like to zip and send?

Comment: @Cleb: you mean you have complete filenames in strings and those files exist on disk? Then use the [`zf.write()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) to add the data from those files to the `ZipFile` object.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed what I ended up with (also using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991745/python-zip-file-and-avoid-directory-structure) to get only the files and avoid the entire directory structure).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried your piece of code and I generate an archive but which seems invalid. 7zip for exemple, is telling me that the file cannot be opened as an archive. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @AlexandreD.: sorry, I don't know how else you treated your binary data; this answer deals specifically with keeping the zipfile object in memory, not on disk.

Comment: Does the memory free up after `send_file` function is executed or do we need to do something for that?@MartijnPieters

Comment: @AniketBote: if your function created the `memory_file` and didn't do anything else than pass it to `send_file()`, it'll be freed once `send_file()` completes.

Comment: In newer versions of flask attachment_name is now download_name