# Python: How to write to file and download it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, file, flask

I a have flask based web service where I trying to download the results to a file to user's desktop (via https).

I tried :

```
def write_results_to_file(results):
    with open('output', 'w') as f:
     f.write('\t'.join(results[1:]) + '\n')
```

this method gets activated when I click export button in the ui.

But I am getting :

```
<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output'
      args = (13, 'Permission denied')
      errno = 13
      filename = 'output'
      message = ''
      strerror = 'Permission denied'
```

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Sounds like a filesystem permissions issue. What operating system are you using? Also, are you writing the file locally or sending it back in the response?

Comment: I am trying to write locally and then send that back to response. Not sure this is the correct way though

Comment: you want to specify the content type in the header and then send the file back in the body. flask provides the send_file method. no need to write to local fs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337013/how-to-send-zip-files-in-the-python-flask-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

The function you posted isn't an actual Flask view function (`app.route()`), so it isn't entirely clear what your server is doing.

This may be closer to the code you need:

```
@app.route("/get_results")
def get_results():
    tsv_plaintext = ''

    # I'm assuming 'results' is a 2D array
    for row in results:
        tsv_plaintext += '\t'.join(row)
        tsv_plaintext += '\n'

    return Response(
        tsv_plaintext,
        mimetype="text/tab-separated-values",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                 "attachment; filename=results.tsv"})
```

(With assistance from [Flask: Download a csv file on clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30043470/4115031))