# How can I send a zip file on the disk to the client with flask and ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337013/how-to-send-zip-files-in-the-python-flask-framework), but I can't use that answer since the ZipFile is generated in another script. In the flask app, I access that zip file saved on the disk.

```
        if download_local:
            file_name = "adyenfiles.zip"
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config["tmp_path"], file_name).replace('\\', '/')
            logging.info(f"Enviando arquivo: {file_path}")
            logging.info(f"FILE_PATH: {file_path}")
            response = make_response(send_file(file_path, as_attachment=True, mimetype="application/zip"))
            response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment;filename={file_name}"
            return response
```

Then on the client:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#manual-download-form").serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#request-download-progress").show();
            displayMessage("Processo de requisição de download iniciado, por favor aguarde.");
        },
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
            $("#manual-download-form")[0].reset();
            $("input[name='date-group']:checked").val("specific");
            $("#date-input-area").html(
                `
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="manual-download-datepicker" name="specific-date" type="text" class="datepicker">
                    <label for="specific-date">Data*</label>
                </div>
                `
            );
            resetDatepicker();
            var filename = "";
            var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }

            var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
            var blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/zip" });

            if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                if (filename) {
                    // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    // safari doesn't support this yet
                    if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                        window.location = downloadUrl;
                    } else {
                        a.href = downloadUrl;
                        a.download = filename;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                    }
                } else {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                }

                setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
            }
        },
        complete: function (response, status, xhr) {
            $("#request-download-progress").hide();
            displayMessage("Se necessário, verifique o diretório para certificar-se de que os arquivos foram baixados.");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            displayMessage(response["responseText"]);
        }
    });
```

I get this error when I try to open the zip file (Stating that it can't be open as a zip file):

[image]

How can I send a zip file that is saved on the disk to the client?? How do I set it up on flask and generate the blob on the client?

Comment: So the whole javascript part is unrelated. You generate the .zip somehow, but can you open the .zip you saved in the `file_path` location? What happens if you just use `send_from_directory` instead of trying to make your own response?

Comment: It works normally if I use "submit" on the form. The zip works normally. The problem is in the blob being generated.

Comment: Do you want to use the zipped file in the browser, or just let the user download the .zip?

Comment: Just download the zip.

Comment: 1) send ajax post 2) generate zip file 3) send download url back from flask to user 4) change windows.location on success to file url